# socket.getaddrinfo raises "Unknown host" mystery

Tags: python, networking, dns

I'm having a problem resolving a hostname using python's (2.6.2) socket class.

From the shell I'm able to ping the hostname, and also resolve the hostname using the `host` command:

```
host myhostname.mydomain.com
```

When I attempt to resolve it with python, a socket.herror exception is raised with the message "[Errno 1] Unknown host"

```
socket.gethostbyaddr("myhostname.mydomain.com")
```

I've recently added the nameservers to resolv.conf, perhaps i need to restart something for python to see these updates?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `gethostbyname`, not `gethostbyaddr` (which does reverse lookup).

```
>>> socket.gethostbyname('car.spillville.com')
'209.20.76.192'
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('209.20.76.192')
('car.spillville.com', [], ['209.20.76.192'])
```